# Replacing characters in MIME encoded emails

Tags: php, encoding, mime

I am looking for a way to simply replace characters with their ASCII counterparts in MIME encoded emails. I've written preliminary code below, but it seems like the `str_replace` commands I'm using will keep on going forever to catch all possible combinations. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

```
<?php
    $strings = "=?utf-8?Q?UK=20Defence=20=2D=20Yes=2C=20Both=20Labour=20and=20Tory=20Need=20To=20Be=20Very=20Much=20Clearer=20On=20Defence?=";

    function decodeString($input){
        $space = array("=?utf-8?Q?","=?UTF-8?Q?", "=20","?=");
        $hyphen = array("=E2=80=93","=2D");
        $dotdotdot = "=E2=80=A6";
        $pound = "=C2=A3";
        $comma = "=2C";
        $decode = str_replace($space, ' ', $input);
        $decode = str_replace($hyphen, '-', $decode);
        $decode = str_replace($pound, '£', $decode);
        $decode = str_replace($comma, ',', $decode);
        $decode = str_replace($dotdotdot, '...', $decode);
        return $decode;
    }

    echo decodeString($strings);
?>
```

Comment: Can you please define "ASCII counterpart"...?

Comment: Well, like =20 is a space and so on. I've figured it out anyways, see answer below.

Comment: Then for future reference: those emails aren't *UTF-8 encoded*, they're *MIME encoded*. UTF-8 has little to do with this per se.

Comment: Yeah, realising this led me to the answer I needed. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out - I have to pass `$strings` to the `mb_decode_mimeheader()` function.